# Spring Boot Config Class not called

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a basic SpringBoot app., embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this main class

```
package com.tdk.iot;

@SpringBootApplication
@Import({SecurityConfig.class })
public class TdkApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TdkApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and this one

```
package com.tdk.iot.config;

    @Configuration
    @Profile("dev")
    @PropertySource("file:///${user.home}/.tdk/application-dev.properties")
    public class DevelopmentConfig {

        @Bean
        public EmailService emailService() {
            return new MockEmailService();
        }

        @Bean
        public ServletRegistrationBean h2ConsoleServletRegistration() {

            ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WebServlet());
            bean.addUrlMappings("/console/*");
            return bean;
        }
    }
```

and this value in the application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

But it seems that is not working since I can't access to the page `/console/*`

Comment: Are you sure your `DevelopmentConfig` bean is loaded by the spring config?

Comment: Are you sure that the directory from which application is started also contains .tdk folder? Because "user.home" is not OS user home directory, but directory from which JVM is started.

Comment: I don't think so and I don't know  why

Comment: Try to remove the `@Profile` annotation

Comment: now its working. How come ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. In the eclipse -> Run configurations -> Arguments the value was also overwritten with other value

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=acc
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move @PropertySource to your SecurityConfig or TdkApplication classes, because you try to load profile property "dev" in class which will be included to context only when profile is "dev" - so Spring can't load property file.